# Android widget: imageView onClick listener

Tags: android, widget, imageview, onclicklistener

I am building a widget for android, and I don't know how to create a onClick listener for ImageView.
The main layout component of widget is RemoteViews, and I have ImageView inside it.
I know I can use PendingIntent to register onClick listener onto RemoteView, but how can I register listener onto ImageView?
Also, which is more important, I need to know coordinates of click. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about getting the co-ordinates but here is the on-click event which fires an intent

use this in the OnUpdate method in the Widget class....

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClassName.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageView, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, I already know about registering pending intent on RemoteView. I am interested how to register onClick listener on ImageView or some other part of RemoteView, and also the coordinates of click